# How do I get ahold of the ID with GetElementByID if the element is "hidden"

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, webbrowser-control

So I am trying to get ahold of the element "g-recaptcha-response" which only displays in the websource when the captcha appears (If you want to look for this element you need to enter the wrong name & password a few times)
This captcha appears all the time for me which is good because I'm trying to locate that specific element by its ID, if you inspect the websource when the captcha is there you will be able to CTRL + F and search for it and it will appear but its.. kinda transparent? Which makes me think its hidden and here comes the issue.

When I try to capture it and give it a value it throws me this error.

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.'

```
private void LoadRS()
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("https://secure.runescape.com/m=weblogin/loginform.ws?mod=www&ssl=0&dest=community");
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("g-recaptcha-response").InnerHtml = "something";
        }
```

[Here is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yn7h6.png)

Any ideas?

EDIT

I was questioning why I could see the element in the element editor on Chrome and not when rightclicking the webpage and I was told that it was because

> the page source is just what is there on initial load the html page
>   inspect element will show everyhthing, stuff that is injected in with
>   js, etc

Now I need to figure out how to get to that element with C#

Comment: I don't really understand your explanation of "hidden" (because "kinda transparent" implies at least partially visible, so...), but if the element is in the DOM then `document.getElementById()` will find it (assuming the ID is unique).

Comment: I dont know the technical term but if you inspect the webpage and search for that element you will find it but its kinda transparent, and I cant find it when I use the method above.

Comment: Your problem seems to be with capital "Document" and capital "GetElementById"

Comment: @ControlAltDel What do you mean? It's not a syntax error.

Comment: Correct not a syntax error. You are just referring to non-existent objects & functions

Comment: If you check the picture you can see that it's "transparent", And it seems like it cant find it because of it.

Comment: @JordanJones *And it seems like it cant find it because of it* - this assumption is wrong. DOM is a structure of elements, it doesn't care if you see this element or even if it is a <script> tag. If it has ID then it will be found. My guess is that `g-recaptcha-response` is a class, but not an ID - I cannot check this, website is blocked by proxy :)

Comment: But lets say I rightclick https://secure.runescape.com/m=weblogin/loginform.ws?mod=www&ssl=0&dest=community and then check the sourcecode the elemt wont be there

Answer (score 0):

It is because the element ("g-recaptcha-response") is generated by the application logic (probably JavaScript).
We need to trigger the element generation before we can get the element.

We can try to click the submit/login button to force element ("g-recaptcha-response") generation. For example in JavaScript:

```
var loginButton = document.querySelector("input[type=submit]");
loginButton.click();

// Add some delay to wait for proper element generation, probably not needed
setTimeout(function() {
  var recaptchaID = document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response");
}, 1000);
```